# Why do my options created with array map method has empty values (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, html-select, array-map

I used a for loop to create an array of month in numbers 1-12.
Then, I am trying to use a map array method to create 12 options for each number.
But the options have empty values.
Here's a sample code:

```
export default ({ experience }) => {
  let monthOptions = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    monthOptions.push(i);
  }
  return (
    
    <select name="month" id="month">
      {
        monthOptions.map((month) => {
          return <option value={month} />;
        })
      }
    </select>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The display value is taken from the `label` attribute or from the tag content, and it's not the same as the actual value that will be passed to the event handlers. To display a value in the options, include it when rendering the tag:

```
<option value={month}>{month}</option>;
```

Or use the `label` attribute:

```
<option value={month} label={month} />
```

Example:

```js
const Example = () => {
  const monthOptions = [];
  
  for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    monthOptions.push(i);
  }
  
  return (
    <select name="month" id="month">
      {
        monthOptions.map((month) => (
          <option key={month} value={month}>{month}</option>
        ))
      }
    </select>  
  )
};
  
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You can shorten your code a bit, using `Array.from()`.

Note: in this example, you can see that the `value`, and the display value are not identical.

```js
const Example = () => (
  <select name="month" id="month">
    {
      Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, month) => (
         <option value={month} key={month}>
            {month + 1}
          </option>
      ))
    }
  </select>  
);
  
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```